# How do I have ubuntu download email then forward that to my mobile devices and other computers?

Tags: 12.10, email

I use a vary secure email service that has a really small quota (under 100 megs), I'd like to have my main ubuntu 12.10 32 bit system to download the mail, delete it off the server, notify my mobile devices. Sure I could set up all my devices to the mail server but if my home system downloads it then deletes I may not get notified of said mail. Anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a mail service for your mobile devices to connect to.

I would: 
setup a second mail account (gmail or something) and forward the mail (on your pc) from the first mail service to the second. then configure your mobile devices to connect to the second mail service. 
However, this kinda beats the purpose of using a very secure mail service. 
You could solve this by more configuration, do not forward the mail but simply send a notification mail to the second mailbox that a mail has arrived in the first. you wont be able to read the mails on your mobile device but you will get notified that there is a mail.

Another solution would be to configure your local system to leave the mails on the server for 24 hours after download. and configure your mobile devices to check the secure mail service.